# How could I run this python script on my webserver? TorBulkExitList.py

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi, cgi-bin

I have a web server that can run python scripts, but I have no experience at all with python. I uploaded the file (TorBulkExitList.py) to my server inside the cgi-bin folder and I tried calling it in the browser but it's giving me a 500 Internal Server Error. Here's the python script:

https://svn.torproject.org/svn/check/trunk/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py

Is there anything I need to do before I could run this script? I didn't change anything from the script at all. Any other alternative, I just need to get a list of the TOR exit IPs. I'm on a Linux/PHP/Apache server btw.

Comment: If I send you a script that will drain all your bank accounts and transfer all the money to me, will you install that, also?  Where did you get this script?  Did they provide any documentation for you to read?  Did you ask them how to install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that file is a [wsgi application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) (because it implements a application method.) You need to configure apache to send requests to it using mod_wsgi (or some other wsgi server.)

Try adding this to the site's .htaccess (with the correct file path):

```
WSGIScriptAlias /TorBulkExitList /usr/local/www/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py
```

and then visit http://example.com/TorBulkExitList

[Click here](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide) to read more about mod_wsgi configuration.